# MutableStateFlow not firing when add item with ViewModel

Tags: kotlin, state, android-jetpack-compose

I need to observe/collect data from Stateflow inside ViewModel when the add method is called. But when I add an item, the state doesn't do recomposition.

This is my ViewModel code:

```
private var _selectedData = MutableStateFlow<MutableList<String>>(mutableListOf())
val data = listOf("Hello", "my", "name", "is", "Claire", "and", "I", "love", "programming")
val selectedData = _selectedData.asStateFlow()
    
fun addSelectedData(index: Int){
    _selectedData.value.add(data[index])
    Log.d("TAG", _selectedData.value.toString())
}
```

And this is my composable code:

```
val mainViewModel: MainViewModel = viewModel()
val selectedData by mainViewModel.selectedData.collectAsState()
LaunchedEffect(key1 = selectedData){
    Log.d("TAG", "SELECTED $selectedData")
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MutableStateFlow` is not able to notice that you modified the object that it holds. You have to set a new object to `MutableStateFlow`, so a new list.

Change the type of `_selectedData` to `MutableStateFlow<List<String>>` and then do:

```kotlin
_selectedData.value = _selectedData.value + data[index]
```

You can make it shorter with:

```kotlin
_selectedData.value += data[index]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr. Broot. This is working, Never thought that we should use List instead of MutableList. 
Sorry if this is out of topic, but can we change the data in the specific index?

Comment: This is not about `List` vs `MutableList`. `list.add(item)` adds to the existing list and `MutableStateFlow` can't know about it. `list + item` doesn't touch existing list, but creates an entirely new list and when we assign it to `MutableStateFlow` it sees the difference. Unfortunately, I believe Kotlin doesn't provide an easy way to create a new list by adding/removing/replacing an item in the middle. Probably the easiest will be to create a mutable copy of the list, modify it and reassign: `val list = _selectedData.value.toMutableList(); list.add(2, "a"); _selectedData.value = list`.